# Incorrect syntax using FFmpeg

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Hello guys i am tring to convert videos using FFmpeg...

1. I moved ffmpeg.exe in same folder with upload.php
2. I tryed this codes in **upload.php**:

   ```
   $randname = (rand(0,1000));
   $file_data=date("d-m-Y-H-i-s");
   $file_name=$file_data.$randname;
   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"vidconvert/".$file_name);
   exec (ffmpeg -i vidconvert/.$file_name videos/.$file_name.mp4);
   echo "Success";
   ```
3. I want to get the file in **vidconvert** folder, and copy converted video to **videos** folder

Note: when i check the **vidconfert** folder, the file is uploaded succesfully

Comment: [Please don't add fake "tags" to your title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). There is a real tagging system; use that instead. Also, smiley faces have no place in the vast majority of SO posts; they never belong in your title.

Comment: You need to put the exec command in quotes; and lose the periods in front of $filename too.

Comment: OK i added:  exec ("ffmpeg -i vidconvert/.$file_name videos/.$file_name.mp4"); but still not working..

Comment: Halid, what does "not working" mean? Do you get an error message? Note that you didn't follow the second part of the previous comment's suggestion.

Comment: No i don't have any error message, just i want to get the video where is uploaded, convert it and move it into the **videos** folder

Answer (score 0):

To see what's going, use:

```
exec ("ffmpeg.exe -i vidconvert/{$file_name} videos/{$file_name}.mp4",$output);
echo $output;
```

the $output will contain the execution results (if any error it should appear in there), and also use relative/full path to files

Comment: This was the answer. Code is working good but slow...  Thank you !